# How can i copy only files which are owned by some user in Linux/unix

Tags: linux, shell, unix

How can i only copy files which are owned by some user. is there a way to specify user name in copy command?
i have few files in my home direct which are owned by some other user, i want to copy only those files to some other directory.How to filter it.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the files owned by user with `find` command and then use `cp` to copy your files.

Example:

find all .txt files from user:

`find /path/to/directory -user <username> -name "*.txt"`

You can pipe it with the `cp` command to copy.

Or a one liner with `find`:

`find /var/www -user vivek -name "*.pl" -exec cp -f source dest`

Comment: Accept the answer if it has helped you. It can provide solution to others having similar question.